# captcha validating in sign in page using Java code

Tags: java, jsp, captcha

I have trying to login in the page with captcha in JSP and Servlet code using the google recaptcha code. I am getting the error as "Recaptcha V1 is shutdown" as follows:

[image]

Code used for captcha:

**JSP page**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>CAPTCHA in Java using reCAPTCHA</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>CAPTCHA in Java Application using reCAPTCHA</h2>
<form action="validate.jsp" method="post">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="user"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
<p>
<%
    ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
                "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", false);
    out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));
%>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>        
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Validate.Jsp**

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl"%>
    <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse"%>

    <html>
<head>
<title>CAPTCHA in Java using reCAPTCHA</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>CAPTCHA in Java Application using reCAPTCHA</h2>
<p>
    <%
        String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
        ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
        reCaptcha.setPrivateKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        String challenge = request
                .getParameter("recaptcha_challenge_field");
        String uresponse = request.getParameter("recaptcha_response_field");
        ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(
                remoteAddr, challenge, uresponse);

        if (reCaptchaResponse.isValid()) {
            String user = request
                    .getParameter("user");
            out.print("CAPTCHA Validation Success! User "+user+" registered.");
    } else {
            out.print("CAPTCHA Validation Failed! Try Again.");
        }
    %>
</p>
<a href=".">Home</a>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the fact that Google deprecated reCaptcha v.1 - you need to upgrade, as described on the corresponding [Google documentation page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/java). This may mean that you'd have to swap for another client library. The short answer is that you cannot continue using your existing set up.

Comment: we have upgraded to version 2.0 but i am not sure what is the step i missed out.

Comment: @Javacoder I suspect the library you are using (tanesha recapture) does not support version 2.  See if you can find a different library.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This the jar "recaptcha4j-0.0.8" i have used . Please let me is this the correct one?

Comment: @Javacoder recaptcha4j is a _very_ old library.  It doesn't support recaptcha v.2. You need to use something completely different. Have a look at this, for example: https://github.com/triologygmbh/reCAPTCHA-V2-java